# Add-PnPApp : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I followed this article in order to use Connect-PnPOnline using ClientID and ClientSecret:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/connect-pnponline-with-appid-and-appsecret.html

https://.sharepoint.com/sites/catalog/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
[image]

https://.sharepoint.com/sites/catalog/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
With that I'm able to successfully connect.

[image]

[image]

After connecting, I have the following script:

```
    # Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId $ClientId -ClientSecret $ClientSecret

    Write-Verbose "Add and publish your app to the App Catalog...."
    Add-PnPApp -Path $Path -Scope Tenant -Overwrite -Publish
    Write-Verbose "Successfully added and published to the App Catalog"
```

And I see the error:

```
Add-PnPApp : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At C:\Scripts\ReleaseManagement\Publish-PnPAppToAppCatalog.ps1:55 char:2
+     Add-PnPApp -Path $Path -Scope Tenant -Overwrite -Publish
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPApp], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Apps.AddApp
```

What am I missing?

Full Script:

```
function Publish-PnPAppToAppCatalog {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $SolutionAbbreviation,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $EnvironmentAbbreviation,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $SiteName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $Path
        
    )
    
    $scriptsDirectory = Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent

    . ($scriptsDirectory + '\Common\Connect-PnPOnlineForPublishApps.ps1')
    Connect-PnPOnlineForPublishApps -SolutionAbbreviation $SolutionAbbreviation `
                                    -EnvironmentAbbreviation $EnvironmentAbbreviation `
                                    -ConnectionType "tenant" `
                                    -SiteName $SiteName `                                   
                                    -Verbose   

    Write-Verbose "Add and publish your app to the App Catalog...."
    Add-PnPApp -Path $Path -Scope Tenant -Overwrite -Publish
    Write-Verbose "Successfully added and published to the App Catalog"           
   
             
}

Publish-PnPAppToAppCatalog -SolutionAbbreviation "" `
-EnvironmentAbbreviation "" `
-SiteName "" `
-Path "" `
-Verbose
```

```
function Connect-PnPOnlineForPublishApps {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $SolutionAbbreviation,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $EnvironmentAbbreviation,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateSet("tenant", "sites")]
        [string] $ConnectionType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [string] $SiteName
       

    )
    #Requires -Version 5
    $scriptsDirectory = Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent

    . ($scriptsDirectory + '\Common\Add-AzAccountIfNeeded.ps1')
    Add-AzAccountIfNeeded
    
    . ($scriptsDirectory + '\Common\Install-AzKeyVaultModuleIfNeeded.ps1')
    Install-AzKeyVaultModuleIfNeeded      

    Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -RequiredVersion "1.10.0" -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
   
        
    #Site collection URL
    $SiteURL = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com"
 
    #Connect to SharePoint Online with ClientId and ClientSecret
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId "<client-id>" -ClientSecret "<client-secret>"
       
    Get-PnPContext

    Set-PnPTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

    Write-Verbose "CONNECTED.................."
```

UPDATE:

I updated the script as per the suggestion:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url $url -Credential $credential
Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false  

#Site collection URL
$SiteURL = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online with ClientId and ClientSecret
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId "<client-id>" -ClientSecret "<client-secret>"
```

I see a Forbidden error:

[image]

Comment: You have the same issue with a Add-PnPFile ?

Comment: Is that same as Add-PnPApp?

Comment: No, it's for adding a file to your sharepoint, to see if you also have the "401 error". 
Add-PnPFile -Path $LocalFileToUpload -Folder "Shared Documents"

Comment: I see the same error

Comment: sure you did not forget the AppPermissionRequests in the XML ? Perhapps delete and re-create the Sharepoint App. Usualy Error 401 is resolved with the solution given by @RaytheonXie-MSFT

Comment: Tried creating again - still the same issue